# To detect the scroll on listview using jquery or jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile and have created a listview. This listview is contained within div and scroll on list is enabled within that div.

I want to perform some task on on the list as scrollstarts on the list. I tried following code:

```
$(".book").scrollstart(function(e) {
  alert("scrolling started!!");
});
```

Binding Jquery mobile 'scrollstart' event to that list doesnt work for me.Please check this fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5wxKx/3/).

But if I bind this event to window then only it works. So is there any way to detect scroll start on that particular list?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<ul>` has not scroll,
so the scroll event never fires.
You have to specify the hieght of `<ul>`:

**CSS**

```
.book {
    overflow: auto;
    height:200px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$( ".book" ).on( "scrollstart", function( event ) {
    alert("scroll");
});
```

Look at the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5wxKx/16/)

If you want to get the scroll of the entry document:

**JS**

```
$(document).on( "scrollstart", function( event ) {
    alert("scroll");
});
```

Comment: I tried it, this works well. But the content is dynamic and so I cant give fixed height to the ul.
It is also possible that I might have few li elements.

Comment: If container not scoll, event scrollstart not fires, that's all!

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle I miss the (document).ready()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".book").scrollstart(function(e) {
          alert("scrolling started!!");
    });
});
```